# Is there a way for me to manage my iCloud settings from the terminal?

Tags: terminal, osx-yosemite, icloud

I am running OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 and would like to administer my iCloud settings (login, which services - Mail, Calendar, Notes - should be used, etc.)

Is there a way for me to manage this via the terminal rather than via System Preferences?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot and untested but in theory  via itunes or libimobiledevice mounting  you should be able to manually tweak the conf files DIRECTLY from a mac /linux/ windows machine (libimobiledevice.org for the tarball to use WITHOUT itunes at all ---itunes tends to "phone home")

Comment: Thanks!  However, I'm looking to configure iCloud settings on a Mac running Yosemite, not for an iOS device.  It looks like libimobiledevice will only allow me to tweak the configuration on a mobile device - do I have that right?